Comedy with a terrorist wearing disguises
Edit to fit "Identify-This-X Questions":
Where you watched the movie or TV show?
It was a movie, watched at home via TV.
When you watched the movie or TV show?
Not sure, like ~10 years ago.
Any idea of how old it was?
~2-3 Years old at the time of watching.
Any idea of country of origin (if known)
99% sure it was US movie.
Whether it was animated or not?
Not animated.
Any distinctive detail?
The movie has several plots but mainly follows a terrorist which has very strange methods of doing his job: he uses hypnosis and strange disguises to achieve his goals, pretends to be blind skyscrapers window cleaner, kidnaps some girl and dresses her as a gorilla etc.

When did u see this movie. Please add more details.

This is the whacky comedy Whoops Apocalypse from 1988, in which a bumbling terrorist called Lacrobat (played by Michael Richards) is ordered to kidnap a princess. He pretends to be a blind window cleaner at some point and also puts the princess in a gorilla suit to sneak her into a hotel.

